# python html parsing fails in document with javascript

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to use Python to parse HTML (although strictly speaking, the server *claims* it's xhtml) and every parser I have tried (ElementTree, minidom, and lxml) all fail.  When I go to look at where the problem is, it's inside a script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
... // some javascript code
    if (condition1 && condition2) { // croaks on this line
```

I see what the problem is, the ampersand should be quoted.  The problem is, this is inside a javascript script tag, so it *cannot* be quoted, because that would break the code.

What's going on here?  How is inline javascript able to break my parse, and what can I do about it?

Update: per request, here is the code used with lxml.

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> tree=etree.parse("http://192.168.1.185/site.html")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3299, in lxml.etree.parse (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:72655)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1791, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:106263)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1817, in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:106564)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1721, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:105561)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1122, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:100456)
  File "parser.pxi", line 580, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:94543)
  File "parser.pxi", line 690, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:96003)
  File "parser.pxi", line 620, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:95050)
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: xmlParseEntityRef: no name, line 77, column 22
```

The [lxml manual](http://lxml.de/3.4/lxmldoc-3.4.0.pdf) starts Chapter 9 by stating "lxml provides a very simple and powerful API for parsing XML and HTML" so I would expect to not see that exception.

Comment: Could you please add a code sample and tell what happens and what you'd expect to happen?

Comment: Maybe there should be an obligatory "don't parse html with an xml parser" rant along the same lines as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/748858).  Try an html parser like beautifulsoup. . .

Comment: @mgilson my understanding from reading the lxml manual is that it (supposedly) can parse HTML.

Comment: @Michael -- That's true.  lxml has a [dedicated html parser](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html).  You could try that... (And, FWIW, you probably know more about this than I do -- I've never done much HTMO parsing :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a lot of really crappy ways for HTML parsing to break. Bad HTML is ubiquitous, and both `script` sections and various templating languages throw monkey wrenches into the works.

But, you also seem to be using XML-oriented parsers for the job, which are stricter and thus much, much more likely to break if not presented with exactly-right, totally valid input. Which most HTML--including most XHTML--manifestly is not.

So, use a parser designed to overlook some of the HTML gotchas:

```
import lxml.html 
d = lxml.html.parse(URL)
```

That should take you off to the races.

Comment: indeed it does, thanks! (although why my other attempt with `lxml.html.etree.parse(URL)` didn't work is beyond me...)

Comment: `lxml` is an amazing library, but it has some very fiddly bits, and not everything has parallel structure. What imports you need is, IMO, one of the places you need to get things *just so*.